Windows Type directories in Ubuntu on multiple drives on Ubuntu Server
I there anyway that I can have my UBUNTU server mimic Windows 11 Directories& Subdirectories as a way to organize them??  John

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? As it stands, the question can be interpreted multiple ways, many of which are probably not what you mean

I am building a Ubuntu server, with several hard hard drives.  I've made a plex server,  but shows the hard drives.without subdirs.  Is there a way to show the directories with the files in them?  These directories were created within Windows 11. John
